# Rails remove string quotes in pragmatically created where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm programming User Defined Views in a Rails app.  I have a table called `uvcondtions` that contains the column(field_name), condition(condition), and compared to (ucompare) to information.

For example:

Field_name = description

ucondition = like

ucompare = Truck

Gets turned into `where table_name.description like "Truck"`

It's working great for most PG SQL conditions. The `in` condition doesn't work.

If I have this in the uvconditions record:

field_name = id

uvcondition = in

uvcompare = (1,3)

I get this error:

PG::Error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near " '(1,3)' "
LINE 1: ...sts"  WHERE "worequests"."tenant_id" = 1 AND (id in '(1,3)')

This is the statements that create the where clause:

```
uvc = uvcondition.ucompare if uvcondition.ucondition == 'in'
@worequests = Worequest.where( uvcondition.field_name + " " + uvcondition.ucondition + " ?",  uvc )
```

Is there any way to remove the quotes around `uvc` ??

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The error is occuring because** `uvc` is actually a string:

```
uvc = "(1,3)"
```

Which misleads Rails to sanitize this string before using it in the SQL query (puttin the extra quotes). Instead of this behavior, Rails should create a list of possible values, made from an Array.

---

Make `uvc` a Ruby array and it **should solve your problem**:

```
uvc = [1, 3]
@worequests = Worequest.where(uvcondition.field_name + " " + uvcondition.ucondition + " ?",  uvc)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!  The field is a string in the database called uvcondition.  Can I convert the string to a Ruby array?

Comment: You definitely could convert it to an array. The first thing that pops to mind (and looks terrible) is `uvc = uvcondition.gsub(/(\(|\))/, '').split(',')`